# Get the first character of a string

Tags: c++, string, char

The title pretty much says it all. I would like to know how to convert a one character string to a char. 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Something wrong with the obvious `str[0]`?

Comment: It helps to not view it as "convert a string to a char" but as "get the first character of a string".

Comment: _"The title pretty much says it all"_ Your title says nothing that I actually know! (voted to close)

Answer (score 8):

That's the relatively simple:

```
char ch = str[0];
```

In other words, just grab the first character from the string, assuming it's not empty.

There's plenty of other stuff you could do, like handling an empty string or skipping leading whitespace, but the code above should be fine for your specific question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the subscript operator on the string, example:

```
string a = "hello";
char b;
if (!a.empty())
  b = a[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

std::string is a container of contiguous characters providing random access to their elements.  There are at least three straight forward ways to retrieve the first character in a string

```
#include <string>
...
std::string string{ "Hello" };

char c1{ string[ 0 ] },    // undefined when called on an empty string
     c2{ string.at( 0 ) }, // will throw if used on an empty string
     c3{ string.front() }; // C++11 equivalent to string[ 0 ]
...
```

Answer (score -1):

String is actually sequence of characters. And you can get any character you want from that sequence.

For example:

if you have string `hello, world` that is just sequence of characters:

`h` `e` `l` `l` `o` `,`  `w` `o` `r` `l` `d`.  Where index of first character `h` is 0 and index of last character is 11.

Same rules apply to one character string:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
  char text[] = "h";
  printf("%s\n", text);

  char first = text[0];
  printf("%c\n", first);

  return 0;
}
```

Here you have string `h` which is sequence of characters containing only one character. :D

Index of character `h` in that string is 0 so you can get that character with `text[0]`.

Comment: @paxdiablo _"Why the downvote, guys?"_ Because just posting code as an answer, without any additional explanation is a ***Bad Answer***. No matter, if the posted code is compilable, or solves the problem in question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks for your comment. It seems that I learned something new today. :)

Comment: Okay you learned how to answer. Now improve your answer!